# Form Validations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I can't quite seem to figure out why my code won't give me an error or success message back to me when I click the submit button. I am just trying to validate strings in an html form to make sure they are not null, not too big, etc.

Developer's tools and the Online Lint have given me no errors. Hopefully you guys can point out any wonky code I have written.

Javscript:

```
function submit()
{
  var firstName = document.getElementById("fn");
  var lastName = document.getElementById("ln");
  var email = document.getElementById("email");
  var emailR = document.getElementById("emailR");
  var userName = document.getElementById("un");
  var password = document.getElementById("pass");
  var passwordR = document.getElementById("passR");
  var error = "";
  var letters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  var postal = document.getElementById("pc");
  var code = /^[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z][ -]?\d[A-Za-z]\d$/;

  if (firstName === null || firstName.length > 15 || !firstName.value.match(letters))
  {
    error += "Please enter a valid first name.";
  }
  if (lastName === null || lastName.length > 15 || !lastName.value.match(letters))
  {
    error += " Please enter a valid last name";
  }

  var ei = email.value.lastIndexOf('@');
  var dot = email.value.lastIndexOf('.');
  if (email === null || email.length < 7 || ei == -1 || dot == -1 || dot < ei + 2)
  {
    error += " Please enter a valid email address";
  }
  if (emailR != email)
  {
    error += " Your email addresses did not match";
  }
  if (postal === null || !postal.length == 7 || !postal.value.match(code))
  {
    error += "Postal code must follow Canadian standard. E.g. \"N3H 1M1\" ";
  }
  if (userName === null || userName.length > 15)
  {
    error += " Please enter a valid username (must be less than 15 characters)";
  }
  if (password === null || password.length > 15)
  {
    error += "please enter a valid password (must be less than 15 characters)";
  }
  if (passwordR != password)
  {
    error += "your passwords do not match";
  }
  if (error === "")
  {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Thank you for signing up!";
  }
  else if (error !== "")
  {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = error;
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Javanoob

Comment: Is the function running? Is the page changing before you can see the messages?

Comment: Mind posting your markup as well? Also just making sure you are calling this function somewhere in your code correct?

Comment: I will post my HTML, the page doesnt change, just the url does.

Comment: @javanoob What do you mean "the page doesn't change, just the url does"? Generally speaking, if the URL has changed, you've been redirected to another page unless the only changes that take place are preceded by a `#`.

Comment: Okay well nothing changes on the page it doesn't even reload the url jjust changes to this file /index.html?firstname=&lastname=&email=&email=&gender=male&pc=&use=personal&un=&pass=&passR=

Comment: stack overflow will not let me post my html, it reads it instead of just posting it as a code, and yes I indented it

Comment: @javanoob Stack Overflow does let you post HTML. Every single line of it has to be indented using 4 spaces and there must be a blank line above the first line of code.

Comment: The forms default action causes a page refresh (as the url change shows). Without seeing the form markup, and how the above function is called, it's not really possible to help further

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementById` gives you the complete HTMLElement object. To get the value of it, use it's `.value` property. Example:

`var email = document.getElementById("email").value;`

(assuming the HTML element with `id = "email"` is a text input)

Comment: @javanoob Then you might want to edit your question and add the HTML this code operates on.